# Bash : how to use a function (which is a string param) in an other function

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, nohup, nice

I have these functions in my .bashrc:

```
# This function just untar a file:
untar()
{
    tar xvf $1
}

# This function execute a command with nohup (you can leave the terminal) and nice for a low priority on the cpu:
nn()
{
    nohup nice -n 15 "$@" &
}
```

Before testing the nn function, I create a tar:

```
echo test > test.txt
tar cvf test.txt.tar test.txt
```

Now what I want to do is:

```
nn untar test.txt.tar
```

But only this works:

```
nn tar xvf test.txt.tar
```

Here the error in nohup.out:

```
nice: ‘untar’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are not first-class citizens. The shell knows what they are, but other commands like `find`, `xargs`, and `nice` do not. To call a function from another program you need to (a) export it to sub-shells, and (b) explicitly invoke a sub-shell.

```
export -f untar
nn bash -c 'untar test.txt.tar'
```

You could automate this if you want to make it easier for the caller:

```
nn() {
    if [[ $(type -t "$1") == function ]]; then
        export -f "$1"
        set -- bash -c '"$@"' bash "$@"
    fi

    nohup nice -n 15 "$@" &
}
```

This line deserves an explanation:

```
set -- bash -c '"$@"' bash "$@"
```

1. `set --` changes the current function's arguments; it replaces `"$@"` with a new set of values.
2. `bash -c '"$@"'` is the explicit subshell invocation.
3. `bash "$@"` are the arguments to the subshell. `bash` is `$0` (not used). The outer existing arguments `"$@"` are passed to the new bash instance as `$1`, `$2`, etc. This is how we get the subshell to execute the function call.

Let's see what happens if you call `nn untar test.txt.tar`. The `type -t` check sees that `untar` is a function. The function is exported. Then `set` changes `nn`'s arguments from `untar test.txt.tar` to `bash -c '"$@"' bash untar test.txt.tar`.